Long pulsed laser rifles as the future of rifles?
Assuming that graphene battery technology is achieved, is it possible to create a deadly long pulsed laser rifle that doesn't have to deal with the logistics of having to transport ammunition?
After handful amount of time trying to view illustrations from research papers, I've learned how long pulse lasers can produce shockwaves, debris, melt zones, and all that mechanically inflicted damage.
I then watched a video of someone trimming trees with a seemingly pulsed laser welder. That got me thinking about the possibility of long pulsed lasers and their effects as a deadly alternative to bullets.
(For clarification, this is for a world building project I made for fun – an AI text based sci Fi role play game set in the future.)

If graphene battery technology achieves the high energy density and rapid discharge rates it's theorized to enable, creating a long-pulsed laser rifle as a deadly weapon could become plausible in a futuristic setting.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Not likely
The US military already uses High Energy Laser weapons capable of taking out light armored vehicles, aircraft, and missiles, and has had this capability for several years now.  The smallest and lightest of these weapon systems weighs in at about 200kg and has a 10kW output.   This said, the DoD has determined that it would only take a 1kW laser to make an effective anti-personnel weapon (assuming an unarmored target); so, given current technologies, one could conceivably make a 20kg anti-personnel laser.
I can not find what % of that 200kg laser is the power source, but Graphene batteries are theoretically 4 times as energy dense as Lithium Ion batteries and a fully loaded modern assault rifle typically only weighs in at 4kg; so, even if it was 100%, this one innovation would still result in a heavier weapon system. Although graphene batteries would bring you closer to a practically light laser rifle, you would need additional, equally significant miniaturization breakthroughs in every aspect of your laser's design to get you close to a rifle weight weapon.
The other issue is maintenance.  Wars are fought by people who have to endure months or even years of extreme conditions.  Mud, dust, and moisture tend to find their ways into everything.  Guns get slammed on the ground and against walls, and all sorts of things that could crack a lense or internal electronics.  Guns tend to be relatively tolerant of foreign particulates and are hard to damage by accident, and they can be field stripped, cleaned, and have parts replaced to keep them in reliable working order without having to leave the front line. This is the biggest limitation to HELs which will likely remain true no matter how good you get at miniaturizing them.  HELs can only be serviced in an electronics clean room because even very tiny foreign contaminants can ruin them.
Bullets can also shoot through smoke and other visual obstructions much more easily.
So, even if you could technically make such a weapon, the reliability advantages of a rifle as a weapon of war will still outweigh any advantages  you might get from using a laser weapon for most common purposes.
Could Mini HELs be useful for anything?
The best thing to use miniaturized HELs for is shooting down missiles and drones.  In theory, you can make a low calibre ADS gun than can shoot them down just as easily as a HEL for a fraction of the cost, but the advantage of lasers in this context is that what goes up does not come down.  AA guns used today pretty much have to fire 25mm HE shells as a bare minimum because you need to be able to load them with a reliable, time delayed self destruct fuse for when they miss or else they will risk a lot of collateral damage. This hard caps how much you can theoretically miniaturize an AA gun system.
Also, due to their size and complexity, these bullets cost ~200 times as much as your standard 5.56 x 45 mm NATO rifle round and the delay to target means that you need to saturate the target's airspace to guarantee a hit.  This means that ADS guns often cost several thousand dollars worth of bullets per target where as a laser can do the job for under a dollar worth of stored electricity needing to only fire one shot.
So, if you could significantly miniaturize HELs, it could mean you could create cheap, man-portal ADS systems.  This would allow you to cover your front line with a distributed network of small ADSs instead of a handful of large armored vehicles making it much harder for artillery or what not to take out your front-line point defenses.
Another possible reason to use miniaturized laser weapons might be for zero-g environments. While your ground infantry may favor guns well into the future, space marines might prefer lasers.  Lasers have no recoil which is a big deal in an environment where unloading a rifle can send you into an uncontrolled backflip.

On maintenance: no moving parts so no problem? Just weld it to be water tight and what maintenance would there be?

@DaniëlvandenBerg soldier dives into cover, rifle strikes the ground - something is now out of alignment, because whatever material you made the rifle from bent, or slightly cracked, or anything like that. Soldier, tired from a day of soldiering, tosses his rifle into the truck instead of carefully putting it down - same thing. And so on. Even if you could make the rifle water tight and dirt is not a problem, impacts will be. And dirt WILL also be a problem, because you need to get rid of waste heat - radiator fins on the outside? Now THOSE will bend and have to be replaced...

On topic of fragility - heard about an Aussie General being shown fancy "ruggedised" tablet for maps & navigation. Could throw around etc. He asked "what happens if I hold it out from behind a wall to see if someone shoots a hole in it? Because I do that with paper maps."

Re "what happens if I hold it out from behind a wall to see if someone shoots a hole in it"... Surely better to use the camera in the tablet to see what is round the corner. Try doing that with a paper map.

@F2Andy try to use the camera in the tablet after s/one round the corner has shot a hole in it. Compare with paper map with a bullet hole in it.

@F2Andy Actually, the paper map method is in many ways more helpful than a tiny camera because a camera will only have the resolution to see if someone is with-in a few meters, but the map will let you know if there are any snipers, hidden or unhidden, at any conceivable range, watching the corner.

... that said, there are other things you can use than a paper map to sniper test a corner.  In WWI, soldiers often used their helmets this same way.

The batteries aren’t necessarily the problem…
Let’s say that you want to blow up a sci-fi-armored human or an unarmored vehicle (will take ~20,000 J of energy, given that a .50 BMG round with that much energy will do the trick) from a range of 100 meters (a long engagement range, but again, approximation). Delivering that much energy before the target can react to your laser rifle’s visual stimulus, i.e. within 250 milliseconds, will require an 80-kilowatt laser, in a vacuum. We’re also assuming that the rifle has some onboard spectrometer so it can identify the target material and change the laser wavelength to ensure maximum energy absorbance by the target, and that even though it might not be a visible laser it still produces visual effects. We’re also assuming that you can keep the gun trained on the target for a full quarter of a second (might be difficult in reality if you’re moving/not braced against something).
80 kilowatts for a quarter of a second isn’t huge. A car battery might be able to store upwards of 2,000,000 J of energy, and if we’re talking about military-grade tech, it might be reasonable to upgrade that to around 5,000,000 J after governmental R&D. That’s still only 250 shots per car battery, but considering that that’s the equivalent of 8-9 30-round chemical-kinetic magazines, it’s not awful. Remember, though, that a regular car battery will only give you 100 shots; if you’re not willing to let some R&D take place, your ammo might be a bit too heavy for your liking.
…it’s the air in the way.
In space, it’s perfectly reasonable to consider a laser weapon that heats up a target’s exterior, eventually either cooking the inhabitants, melting through the hull, or forcing the ship to surrender after the radiators begin to fail. But in air, you have something standing in the way of you and the target.
There’s been some NASA research on $\text{CO}_2$ laser light propagation in air. The worst figure I see there is 10 decibels (per meter, presumably); assuming our laser tech is super high-end and we get to one decibel per meter, consistently, across all domains, then that leads to an order-of-magnitude drop of 0.1, a loss of around 5% total energy, for each meter the laser beam has to travel.
At short distances, we could get away with it - Nosajimiki points out that even a 1kW laser would work as a simple anti-personnel weapon, so in close-quarters closed environments, this would likely be effective, though in close-quarters high-intensity environments, I think you’d want something faster and easier to use, like a regular gun, instead of a big bulky laser cannon that doesn’t work if you can’t hold it on a target for a quarter of a second.
At long distances, however, that 5% gets in the way. At ten meters, you need to put in around 63% more power at the gun to get the same amount of power into the target; at 25 meters, you need aroud 3.4 times as much power. At 100 meters, you need over a hundred and thirty times the power that you need at one meter to deliver the same energy to the target over the same time interval.
So, let’s magic away the power problems, hook the laser cannon up to a flux capacitor, and just start with 10.48 megawatts instead of 80 kilowatts. Good? Bad. Keep in mind that the air is still absorbing heat - that 5% of 10.48 megawatts is still a grand total of 131 kilojoules of energy over the course of firing. That’s on par with the amount of energy released by a small hand grenade and enough to heat the air by over 100 degrees Celsius, keep in mind, and that’s just in the first meter. You’re going to end up delivering way more energy to the surrounding air than to the actual target.
Is that a bad thing?
It means you’re wasting a lot of energy, and it means that your soldiers will need thermal shielding to avoid accidentally cooking themselves. It also means that you don’t really need to hit your targets at medium range: firing all over the place and giving them heatstroke might be good enough. But if what you want is a laser gun, it’s going to work best outside the atmosphere.
Note that laser guns aren’t especially flashy, if that’s what you’re going for. A lot of the time lasers are thought of as these cool lines of light that extend from one point to another instantly, but the truth is the only reason you see that in movies/TV is because either it’s CGI and fake to begin with or they put fog down for the laser to reflect off of (which will make it much less efficient than one decibel per meter). In reality, a laser cannon would just produce a flash at the gun and a flash at the target - nothing special.
In the context of actual worldbuilding, I would recommend using a regular chemical-kinetic gun (or, in especially sci-fi worlds, an electromagnetic-kinetic gun) instead. Instead of mucking around with lasers and optics and batteries and laser absorptance and all this stuff, it’s often better to use the tried-and-true method of throwing something at someone really hard.

How far would a 10-megawatt laser reach, or some kind of high powered laser? Assuming this weapon is connected to a compact fusion reactor producing 100MW of power

In space, as far as your collimation allows. In atmosphere, 10 megawatts initially, with current assumptions, would reach around 95 meters (as in, it will deliver 80 kW to a target at that distance given 1dB/m falloff). Just watch out for air heating.

Didn't the AN/SEQ-3 reach a range of 1mile with just 15-50kw? Or is that based on the "as deadly to humans as a bullet" criteria?

That’s based on the assumption I made that you want to blow up a human. Laser weapons in use are more “melt the drone after a few seconds” if I’m not mistaken; the assumption I used was “explode it”. Plus, those weapons’ apertures are larger than a rifle barrelso the laser would probably have much lower energy per unit beam area (and thus much lower air absorption per unit distance), but it also means you couldn’t carry it as a rifle.

100m is a pretty close engagement range.

I believe your atmosphere absorption figures are what they would be if you attuned your laser to the worst possible wavelengths, not the best.  HELs can take out targets several km away under normal atmospheric conditions.

Also, modern HELs can take down a target in under a second.  I've read several figures about 0.25-0.8 second hold times depending on the target and laser system in question.

@Nosajimiki That’s what the NASA figure seems to imply. Account, though, that you’re likely to do something about it (steam/smoke grenades, the like) if you know opposing combatants are equipped with laser rifles, which would probably make things even worse than it looks here. I actually indirectly know someone who has operated an HEL in the military, yeah they work, but in the cases I’ve heard of at least it’s a single pretty-much-oblivious target in the air with zero anti-laser countermeasures.

@controlgroup I agree. That is why the Navy is focusing on 300-500kW lasers even though 25-50kW is enough to blast through a light armored vehicle. It's to make sure there is a big margin of error for laser resistant targets and sub-optimal conditions.  That said, you make a good point that ground targets are much easier to make laser resistant than air targets because you can smoke screen them, and they are not nearly as sensitive to pressure shockwaves as a kill or disabling mechanism.

@controlgroup what about using the long pulsed configuration for ranges where it shoots down aircrafts and missiles? Would there be any improvement (considering it's mechanically-inflicted effects like debris and shockwaves) compared to just melting through the airframe?

You could probably deal a fair bit of mechanical damage, yeah. I’d warn you that the more mech damage you want to do the longer the pulses’ll take so the longer you’ll have to keep the rifle trained on the target, but it’d probably work fairly well.

I did read about the femtosecond laser just straight up vaporizing material, no shockwaves or debris. Is that a good thing, at least in other applications in combat? Or is it better to just retain that explode-y effect on target that the longer pulsed lasers offer?

The idea is interesting, but current tech isn’t good enough to get the actual energy delivered high enough, or getting that into a compact repeated-use package. If we’re talking a few decades/centuries into the future, I’d buy that, though. Id imagine it’d have roughly the same effect that the Star Trek producers made the Klingon disruptors have in some cases - bolt of light (from plasma production), disintegration. Less clutter after the fact is a plus.

So the problem is that CO2 lasers have huge absorption in air? Just use another laser at a different wavelength?

Good luck finding a wavelength that a) you can produce in a compact device in an energy-efficient way (see other answers), b) is absorbed strongly by the target to actually deliver energy, and c) is not absorbed by air.

So I'm hearing that a laser weapon in the atmosphere might be not so much a rifle alternative as a flamethrower alternative.  That could still be a fearsome weapon.

True! The nice thing about flamethrowers, though, is that you can get it the fire at least a little bit away from you before it expands into a big cone of hurt; with a laser I’d imagine the hurt would be more localized towards you. Then again, if you modify it to deflect that heat away (IR reflectors, mirrors, etc) and tune the laser to intentionally be absorbed by the air… that could be effective

Something else to keep in mind that lasers are not terribly efficient. If we say that they're able to get 50% efficiency (so 50% of the power goes into the beam, the other 50% is waste heat) your hand held laser rifle is going to be heated just as much as your target. (Probably more considering atmospheric losses, scattering, spallation, etc)
Vehicle mounted laser systems can integrate cooling systems to dissipate that heat over a larger surface area, while concentrating the beam on a tiny surface area on the target.
Your hand held rifle will have a smaller surface area, and less spare power to run a cooling system.
Regular firearms get real hot too, but have bullets and casings that carry heat away. They have mechanical systems that are designed to handle that heat stress. Are sensitive electronics and optics going to be able to handle the same kind of punishment?
The advantages are being able to hit a distant target near instantly, silently, with no recoil, and potentially with an invisible beam.
I would wager that "hand held" laser systems might find a use as a Sniper role, with a weapon that is more similar to heavy bipod sniper rifles (but doesn't necessarily need a huge barrel).
The logistics of carrying ammo around is a pain, but it is a problem that we've solved over hundreds of years of warfare. Widely deployed energy weapons will need to add a very generous power supply to that supply chain.
Consider how many square meters of solar panels would be needed just to power a single day's operation of a standard infantry laser rifle?
If you're shipping in fresh batteries and returning expending ones (or just discarding them if it isn't worth it), you still have an ammo logistic issue.

Ah, I see. I was asking under the assumption that graphene batteries and solar paint combos (plus that portable generator the size of a soda can that the US military is working on) are already in widespread use.

A note on your snipers: for them, the advantage of the laser is not only "no recoil" and "near instantly" but also "bullet drop, coriolis effect and wind will not affect the targetting" - but in return, "smog/fog/... will affect the power delivered (because they increase the atmospheric absorption)". So you'll hit more easily, but you might need to scale the rifles a bit bigger if you don't want to shoot only on clear days.

@Vexorr the maximum amount of energy you can get with solar panels is around 1kw per square meter.  We're going to need a decent area of those back at base to charge X battery packs for Y soldiers with Z in reserve.
Maybe that's tenable if suppressive fire isn't really in the combat doctrine?
If soldiers with Laser Rifle are bringing spare battery packs into the field, holding onto expended ones, and bringing them back to base to charge, you still have an ammo logistics issue.
If you're powering the systems with fossil fuels, you've still got an ammo logistics issue.

To cut out any logistic requirement, you could opt for fission power.
Portable Fission reactors for a personnel power plant is a terrible idea for many reasons.
Modular Fission reactors to power forward operating bases isn't a terrible idea, until you consider the fallout from those being bombarded or captured.
We already use fission to power Air Craft Carriers and Submarines, but if those get destroyed, well, people don't live in the oceans.
Regardless, solving the power problem does not solve the heat dissipation problem.
